# TNG Season 5 Episode 15 - Is the O'Brien newborn child possessed, and is this event ever revisited/resolved/debunked?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

At the end of Star Trek TNG S5E15 - "Power Play" just before the curtain falls  the show suggests that **the newborn child of Chief Miles and Keiko O'Brien has been possessed**.

Is this event ever revisited/resolved/debunked anywhere in Star Trek canon?

#### Spoiler Questions

> Since this was a penal colony, did a prisoner escape? 
>  For how long if the child was actually possessed?

It's a somewhat disturbing event in the show for me, I would hate to think it was left open ended by writers/producers. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> the show suggests that the newborn child of Chief Miles and Keiko O'Brien has been possessed

No it doesn’t. Here’s the original script:

> KEIKO: I'm just glad to have you back.
>
> O'BRIEN: If I could've killed that thing inside me... I would have...
>
> KEIKO: I know.
>
> *Molly smiles...*
>
> KEIKO: *(continuing)* We both know.
>
> *He exchanges a loving glance with his wife, hugs her and the baby.*

No implication of baby-possession there.

The director chose to film this with a slow zoom into Molly’s face, which is I presume what makes you think that possession was implied.

I think the zoom is likely just intended to illustrate the most important thing in the O’Briens’ lives, their daughter, and to give us, the audience, a cute baby close-up to coo over. If possession were intended to be implied, I would have thought they’d at least add some creepy music, [like at the end of *Conspiracy*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Conspiracy_(episode)#Summary) in season one.

If it helps, following this episode (spoilers)

> Molly O’Brien continues to grow up reasonably happily throughout *The Next Generation* and *Deep Space Nine*, and at all times acts like a fairly irritating child as opposed to a convicted murder trapped in an infant girl’s body.

Comment: I should have been more clear. as a viewer I always assume the director shot according to the script, and so yes I did believe that the child smiling with the slow zoom and focus was to suggest an inmate had successfully escaped using a crew member that couldn't have been confronted (the child.) thanks, accepted for the DS9 reference which qualifies as supporting canon for me :) (and then marked it as spoiler info) thanks!

Answer (score 13):

This [original script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/215.txt) gives no mention of this interpretation. It specifically calls out that the episode has ended "*happily*".

> **KEIKO:** *I'm just glad to have you back.*
>
> **O'BRIEN:** *If I could've killed that thing inside me... I would have...*
>
> **KEIKO:** *I know.*
>
> Molly smiles...
>
> **KEIKO:** (continuing) *We both know.*
>
> He exchanges a loving glance with his wife, hugs her and the baby. And
> as Picard, Troi and Beverly look over, **pleased that the long nightmare
> has ended happily, we...**
>
> 107  EXT. SPACE - THE ENTERPRISE (OPTICAL)
>
> As it leaves orbit of the stormy moon...

---

The slow lingering look at the child at the end (coupled with the chat with the O'Briens) seems to have served to emphasise to the audience that there was **no lasting injury to Molly, either physically or emotionally.**